# Artificer's Thunder Monger

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, artificer

Does anyone know where I can find either the Thunder Monger stats, or the Gun Smith class for the Artificer? I have checked practically everywhere on player class book guides, and even in equipment book, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Which game and edition are you asking about?

Comment: @guildsbounty I’m about 99% sure there existed games that had something called “artificer” prior to Eberron.

Comment: @guildsbounty I've just updated what edition im looking for.

Comment: @user43068 I’ve done it for you this time, but for the record, that information should go in the tags rather than in the question’s body. Just so you know. (In the body isn’t really “wrong” but it definitely needs to be in the tags.) Anyway, voting to reopen this, but you might consider adding where you heard of these things/why you think they exist even though you can’t find them, that context can help people answer the question.

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** you're asking about *4e* D&D? Because no official WotC content for 4e contains a Gun Smith class or Thunder Monger weapon, while those **are** real things for *5e* D&D.

Comment: @ObliviousSage could you help me find it then, at this point i'm just looking for it

Comment: If you're playing **4e** then you're looking for a thing that *does not exist*. If you're playing **5e** then guildsbounty's answer will tell you where to find it.

Comment: @Oblivioussage Is this a person

Comment: The answer directly below these comments was posted by the user *guildsbounty*, and it includes a link to where you can find the **5e** version of the Gunsmith archetype, which includes an ability called Thunder Monger.

Answer (score 5):

## This specialization does not exist in 4E

The Gunsmith Artificer, complete with the Thunder Monger power is a brand new addition that was introduced in the D&D 5E's Unearthed Arcana playtest materials, found [here](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf).

Prior to 5E there is no official D&D (or Pathfinder, for that matter) content that paints an Artificer as a gun-wielder.

This was a sufficiently striking change from how Artificers worked in 3.5/4e that Keith Baker, the guy who invented the Eberron setting (which introduced Artificers to Dungeons and Dragons) [posted on his blog](http://keith-baker.com/dragonmarks-the-evolving-artificer/) to talk about how weird he thought it was to give the magi-scientist with a specialization in enchanting stuff for themselves and others...an actual gun.

If you're still looking to play D&D 4E, then I unfortunately have to tell you that the Gunsmith specialization does not exist in the edition you're playing. It was introduced in 5E.